# K-means clustering in Rust

Tags: beginner, rust, clustering

I've implemented K-means clustering in Rust.  It's my second Rust project (my first one is here: [Randomly selecting an adjective and noun, combining them into a message](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125065/randomly-selecting-an-adjective-and-noun-combining-them-into-a-message))

I would like advice on whether I am doing stuff idiomatically, and any sensible optimisations I could make.  I also appreciate advice on code-style -- I care a lot about having code that is readable and formatted nicely, but I'm still getting the hang of it in Rust.

A brief explanation of the K-means algorithm:

- You have a set of data you wish to partition into a known number of groups, a.k.a. clusters
- The mean of all the data belonging to a cluster is the cluster's centroid.  You decide which cluster a datum belongs to by selecting the cluster which is closest, i.e. the one at the smallest Euclidean distance from the data point
- The algorithm works in two iterative steps.  First, we initialise the cluster centroids, then:

  - Assign all the data to their nearest centroid
  - Update the cluster centroids so that they are the mean of all the points assigned to them
  - Repeat until a local minimum is found

Here is the contents of lib.rs, now including my unit tests (I realise I could probably have more tests D:):

```
use std::path::Path;

extern crate csv;
extern crate rustc_serialize;

/// Store one data point's (or one cluster centroid's) x and y co-ordinates
#[derive(Clone, Debug, RustcDecodable)]
pub struct DataPoint {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
}

/// Structure for holding data point's assignments to clusters
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Assignment<'a> {
    data_point: &'a DataPoint,
    cluster_ind: usize,
}


pub fn read_data<P>(file_path: P) -> Vec<DataPoint> where P: AsRef<Path> {
    let mut data = vec![];
    let mut reader = csv::Reader::from_file(file_path).unwrap();
    for data_point in reader.decode() {
        let data_point: DataPoint = data_point.unwrap();
        data.push(data_point);
    }
    data
}


pub fn squared_euclidean_distance(point_a: &DataPoint,
                                  point_b: &DataPoint) -> f64 {
   (point_b.x - point_a.x).powi(2) + (point_b.y - point_a.y).powi(2)
}


pub fn get_index_of_min_val(floats: &Vec<f64>) -> usize {

    floats.iter()
          .enumerate()
          .fold(0,
                | min_ind, (ind, &val) |
                if val == f64::min(floats[min_ind], val) { ind }
                else { min_ind })
}

/// Assign points to clusters
fn expectation<'a>(data: &'a Vec<DataPoint>,
                   cluster_centroids: &Vec<DataPoint>) -> Vec<(Assignment<'a>)> {

    let mut assignments: Vec<(Assignment)> = vec![];
    for point in data {
        let mut distance: Vec<f64> = vec![];
        for cluster in cluster_centroids {
            distance.push(squared_euclidean_distance(&point, cluster));
        }
        assignments.push(Assignment{data_point: point,
                                    cluster_ind: get_index_of_min_val(&distance)});
    }
    assignments
}

pub fn count_assignments(assignments: &Vec<Assignment>,
                         cluster_ind: usize) -> usize {
    let points_in_cluster = get_points_in_cluster(assignments, cluster_ind);
    points_in_cluster.len()
}

pub fn get_points_in_cluster<'a>(assignments: &'a Vec<Assignment>,
                                 cluster_ind: usize) -> Vec<Assignment<'a>> {
    let mut points_in_cluster = assignments.clone();
    points_in_cluster.retain(|&Assignment{data_point: _,
                                          cluster_ind: a}| a == cluster_ind);
    points_in_cluster
}

pub fn sum_assigned_values(assignments: &Vec<Assignment>,
                           cluster_ind: usize) -> DataPoint {
    let points_in_cluster = get_points_in_cluster(assignments, cluster_ind);
    let (mut x_tot, mut y_tot) = (0.0_f64, 0.0_f64);
    for point in points_in_cluster {
        x_tot += point.data_point.x;
        y_tot += point.data_point.y;
    }
    DataPoint{x: x_tot, y: y_tot}
}

/// Update cluster centres
fn maximisation(cluster_centroids: &mut Vec<DataPoint>,
                assignments: &Vec<(Assignment)>) {

    for i in 0..cluster_centroids.len() {
        let num_points = count_assignments(&assignments, i);
        let sum_points = sum_assigned_values(&assignments, i);
        cluster_centroids[i] = DataPoint{
            x: sum_points.x/num_points as f64,
            y: sum_points.y/num_points as f64};
    }
}

pub fn get_error_metric(cluster_centroids: &Vec<DataPoint>,
                        assignments: &Vec<Assignment>) -> f64 {
        let mut error = 0.0;
        for i in 0..assignments.len() {
            let cluster_ind = assignments[i].cluster_ind;
            error += squared_euclidean_distance(assignments[i].data_point,
                                                &cluster_centroids[cluster_ind]);
        }
        error
    }

pub fn kmeans_one_iteration<'a>(cluster_centroids: &mut Vec<DataPoint>,
                                data: &'a Vec<DataPoint>) -> Vec<Assignment<'a>> {
    let assignments = expectation(data, cluster_centroids);
    maximisation(cluster_centroids, &assignments);
    assignments
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_squared_euclidean_distance_simple_case() {
        let origin = DataPoint{x: 0.0, y: 0.0};
        let point = DataPoint{x: 1.0, y: 1.0};
        let expected = 2.0;
        let actual = squared_euclidean_distance(&origin, &point);
        assert_eq!(expected, actual)
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_squared_euclidean_distance_gives_0_for_same_point() {
        let point_a = DataPoint{x: -999.3, y: 10.5};
        let point_b = point_a.clone();
        let expected = 0.0;
        let actual = squared_euclidean_distance(&point_a, &point_b);
        assert_eq!(expected, actual)
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_get_index_of_min_val() {
        let floats = vec![0.0_f64, 1.0_f64, 3.0_f64, -5.5_f64];
        let expected = 3;
        let actual = get_index_of_min_val(&floats);
        assert_eq!(expected, actual)
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_count_assignments_returns_0_when_no_occurences() {
        let dp = DataPoint{x: 0.0, y: 0.0};
        let assignments = vec![Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 1},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 5},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0}];
        let cluster_ind: usize = 4;
        let expected = 0;
        let actual = count_assignments(&assignments, cluster_ind);
        assert_eq!(expected, actual)
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_count_assignments_returns_3_when_3_occurences() {
        let dp = DataPoint{x: 0.0, y: 0.0};
        let assignments = vec![Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 1},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 5},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0}];
        let cluster_ind: usize = 0;
        let expected = 3;
        let actual = count_assignments(&assignments, cluster_ind);
        assert_eq!(expected, actual)
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_sum_assigned_values_returns_0_when_none_assigned() {
        let dp = DataPoint{x: 5.0, y: 5.0};
        let assignments = vec![Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 1},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 5},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0}];
        let cluster_ind: usize = 2;
        let expected = DataPoint{x: 0.0, y: 0.0};
        let actual = sum_assigned_values(&assignments, cluster_ind);
        assert_eq!(expected.x, actual.x);
        assert_eq!(expected.y, actual.y)
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_sum_assigned_values_returns_correctly_when_some_assigned() {
        let dp = DataPoint{x: 1.0, y: 1.0};
        let assignments = vec![Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 1},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 5},
                               Assignment{data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0}];
        let cluster_ind: usize = 0;
        let expected = DataPoint{x: 3.0, y: 3.0};
        let actual = sum_assigned_values(&assignments, cluster_ind);
        assert_eq!(expected.x, actual.x);
        assert_eq!(expected.y, actual.y)
    }
}
```

And here is the contents of main.rs:

```
extern crate kmeans;

use kmeans::*;

fn main() {
    let data = read_data("../../data/faithful.csv");
    let mut cluster_centroids = vec![DataPoint{x: 2.0, y: 50.0},
                                     DataPoint{x: 7.0, y: 100.0}];
    let (mut error, mut prev_error) = (0.0, -1.0);
    let mut assignments: Vec<Assignment>;
    while error != prev_error {
        prev_error = error;
        assignments = kmeans_one_iteration(&mut cluster_centroids, &data);
        error = get_error_metric(&cluster_centroids, &assignments);
        println!("{}", error);
    }
}
```

I appreciate any advice! :D

Comment: Good point -- I'll add them in now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `DataPoint` is a small enough structure, it might as well be `Copy`.
2. `squared_euclidean_distance` can be an instance method on `DataPoint`.
3. `where` clauses should be placed on a separate line. This makes
   it easier to see what constraints a function has.
4. It's rarely needed to declare a container (like a `Vec`) and
   then fill it up manually. Use iterator adapters instead; `map` and
   `collect` are the big two. Think about iterator adapters any time
   you use a `for` loop that's not just for side effects.
5. Prefer `expect` over `unwrap`. For `Result`s, it includes the
   underlying error message. In either case, it allows you or the user
   to track down the error easier.
6. Reading from a file should have better error handling than
   panicking; does tying the library to CSV even make sense? Maybe this
   really belongs in the executable?
7. Never take `&Vec<T>` or `&String`. `&[T]` or `&str` is broader
   and gives you everything you need.
8. There are no spaces inside the closure argument list delimiters
   (`|`).
9. Use braces for multi-line closures
10. It doesn't make sense to return 0 for the minimum value of an
    empty slice (or zero-length iterator). This is what `Option` is
    made for.
11. A few places that create a `Vec` from an iterator just to
    iterate over it again. It's more efficient to never collect.
12. `get` is pretty useless in method names. Dropping it loses
    nothing.
13. When the first thing a function does is convert to an iterator,
    you might as well just accept anything that can be made into an
    iterator.
14. Include spaces around a type constructors `{` and before the `}`.
15. There's no reason to include parenthesis in `Vec<(T)>`.
16. When you have a multi-line function argument list, place the `{` on a new line.
17. Use iterator adapters instead of cloning a slice / `Vec` and
    then `retain`ing values.
18. There's no reason to return a vector when you just convert it
    into an iterator. I used `Box<Iterator>` for laziness.
19. The code computes `points_in_cluster` twice. It's probably more
    efficient to combine the calculations.
20. There's no reason to make a mutable tuple and then convert into
    a struct, just mutate the struct directly.
21. Instead of a `for` loop, use `fold`.
22. Implement addition for `DataPoint` to make it simpler to understand.
23. Does it make sense to return 0, 0 for the sum of an empty slice?
24. Use `iter_mut` and `enumerate` instead of poking at the slices
    value via array index (iterators are more efficient).

---

```
use std::path::Path;

extern crate csv;
extern crate rustc_serialize;

/// Store one data point's (or one cluster centroid's) x and y co-ordinates
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, RustcDecodable)]
pub struct DataPoint {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
}

impl DataPoint {
    fn zero() -> DataPoint {
        DataPoint {
            x: 0.0,
            y: 0.0,
        }
    }

    pub fn squared_euclidean_distance(&self, other: &DataPoint) -> f64 {
        (other.x - self.x).powi(2) + (other.y - self.y).powi(2)
    }
}

impl std::ops::Add for DataPoint {
    type Output = DataPoint;

    fn add(self, other: DataPoint) -> DataPoint {
        DataPoint {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
        }
    }
}

/// Structure for holding data point's assignments to clusters
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Assignment<'a> {
    data_point: &'a DataPoint,
    cluster_ind: usize,
}

pub fn read_data<P>(file_path: P) -> Vec<DataPoint>
    where P: AsRef<Path>
{
    let mut reader = csv::Reader::from_file(file_path).unwrap();
    reader.decode().map(|point| point.unwrap()).collect()
}

pub fn index_of_min_val<I>(floats: I) -> Option<usize>
    where I: IntoIterator<Item = f64>,
{
    let mut iter = floats.into_iter().enumerate();

    iter.next().map(|(i, min)| {
        iter.fold((i, min), |(min_i, min_val), (i, val)| {
            if val < min_val {
                (i, val)
            } else {
                (min_i, min_val)
            }
        }).0
    })
}


/// Assign points to clusters
fn expectation<'a>(data: &'a [DataPoint],
                   cluster_centroids: &[DataPoint]) -> Vec<Assignment<'a>>
{
    data.iter().map(|point| {
        let distances = cluster_centroids.iter().map(|cluster| point.squared_euclidean_distance(cluster));
        let index = index_of_min_val(distances).expect("No minimum value found");
        Assignment { data_point: point, cluster_ind: index }
    }).collect()
}

pub fn count_assignments(assignments: &[Assignment],
                         cluster_ind: usize) -> usize
{
    points_in_cluster(assignments, cluster_ind).count()
}


pub fn points_in_cluster<'a>(assignments: &'a [Assignment],
                                 expected_cluster_ind: usize) -> Box<Iterator<Item = Assignment<'a>> + 'a>
{
    let i = assignments.into_iter()
        .cloned()
        .filter(move |&Assignment { cluster_ind, .. }| expected_cluster_ind == cluster_ind);
    Box::new(i)
}

pub fn sum_assigned_values(assignments: &[Assignment],
                           cluster_ind: usize) -> DataPoint
{
    points_in_cluster(assignments, cluster_ind)
        .into_iter()
        .fold(DataPoint::zero(), |acc, point| acc + *point.data_point)
}


/// Update cluster centres
fn maximisation(cluster_centroids: &mut [DataPoint],
                assignments: &[Assignment])
{
    for (i, centroid) in cluster_centroids.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        let num_points = count_assignments(&assignments, i);
        let sum_points = sum_assigned_values(&assignments, i);
        *centroid = DataPoint {
            x: sum_points.x / num_points as f64,
            y: sum_points.y / num_points as f64
        };
    }
}

pub fn get_error_metric(cluster_centroids: &[DataPoint],
                        assignments: &[Assignment]) -> f64
{
    assignments.iter().fold(0.0, |error, assignment| {
        let centroid = &cluster_centroids[assignment.cluster_ind];
        error + assignment.data_point.squared_euclidean_distance(centroid)
    })
}

pub fn kmeans_one_iteration<'a>(cluster_centroids: &mut [DataPoint],
                                data: &'a [DataPoint]) -> Vec<Assignment<'a>>
{
    let assignments = expectation(data, cluster_centroids);
    maximisation(cluster_centroids, &assignments);
    assignments
}
```

---

The tests are straight-forward, but there are some small changes I would make to tighten them up:

1. Because we now accept slices instead of `&Vec`, we don't need to create as many vectors. This is a small efficiency gain.
2. Implementing `PartialEq` (via `derive`) for `DataPoint` means you don't have to compare the properties individually.
3. I didn't find many of the variables introduced to be useful, so I inlined most of them while keeping line length shorter. I wish that Rust's testing framework made more of a distinction between expected and actual values, but it doesn't...

---

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_squared_euclidean_distance_simple_case() {
        let origin = DataPoint { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 };
        let point = DataPoint { x: 1.0, y: 1.0 };
        assert_eq!(2.0, origin.squared_euclidean_distance(&point))
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_squared_euclidean_distance_gives_0_for_same_point() {
        let point_a = DataPoint { x: -999.3, y: 10.5 };
        assert_eq!(0.0, point_a.squared_euclidean_distance(&point_a));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_index_of_min_val() {
        let floats = vec![0.0_f64, 1.0_f64, 3.0_f64, -5.5_f64];
        assert_eq!(Some(3), index_of_min_val(floats))
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_count_assignments_returns_0_when_no_occurences() {
        let dp = DataPoint { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 };
        let assignments = [Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 1 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 5 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0 }];
        assert_eq!(0, count_assignments(&assignments, 4))
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_count_assignments_returns_3_when_3_occurences() {
        let dp = DataPoint { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 };
        let assignments = [Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 1 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 5 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0 }];
        assert_eq!(3, count_assignments(&assignments, 0));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_sum_assigned_values_returns_0_when_none_assigned() {
        let dp = DataPoint { x: 5.0, y: 5.0 };
        let assignments = [Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 1 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 5 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0 }];
        assert_eq!(DataPoint { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 }, sum_assigned_values(&assignments, 2))
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_sum_assigned_values_returns_correctly_when_some_assigned() {
        let dp = DataPoint { x: 1.0, y: 1.0 };
        let assignments = [Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 1 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 5 },
                           Assignment { data_point: &dp, cluster_ind: 0 }];
        assert_eq!(DataPoint { x: 3.0, y: 3.0 }, sum_assigned_values(&assignments, 0));
    }
}
```

---

> Can we not just return `i` from `points_in_cluster`? Could you explain why you need to create a `Box`?

This is probably best answered by [Correct way to return an Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423).

> My understanding: returning a trait causes problems as it doesn't have a defined size. Allocating on the heap makes sense when you don't statically know the size needed. Iterator is a trait, so this applies here.

That sounds about right. I said I was being lazy because if I cared about maximal performance, I could have defined my own iterator that wouldn't need any heap allocation. A [future version of Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1522) is likely to allow returning a statically-known concrete type that is guaranteed to implement a trait but without explicitly listing the type.

> In the same function you appear to use a `move` keyword. I can't seem to find up to date docs for this.

The [*The Rust Programming Language* section on closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/closures.html#move-closures) discusses the `move` keyword. In this case, we are transferring ownership of `expected_cluster_ind` to the closure.

Comment: These all look very helpful -- I'm a bit busy atm but next week I will find time to go through them all, and update my code :)

Comment: I realise this is months old -- I finally got back to this after being busy on other projects.  Could you explain the changes to the points_in_cluster function a bit more?  In particular point 18 in your list.  Why do you need to create a Box?  Can we not just return i (from points_in_cluster method)?

Comment: @lochsh does http://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423 answer your question?

Comment: I think that helps a lot.  My understanding: returning a trait causes problems as it doesn't have a defined size.  Allocating on the heap makes sense when you don't statically know the size needed.  Iterator is a trait, so this applies here.  Is that an accurate summary? Thanks again

Comment: In the same function you appear to use a `move` keyword.  Is that right?  I can't seem to find up to date docs for this.  Have I misunderstood, or is this something that isn't in Rust anymore?

Comment: @lochsh updated